# Graph Theory proof regarding edge connectivity

Tags: graph-theory

I can't seem to figure out this proof. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Prove that if G is a graph of order *p* and minimum degree of G (d(G)) >= p/2, then the edge connectivity of G (k_1(G))= minimum degree of G.

Relevant statements:
I'm not sure that this is relevant.. but d(G)>=(|V(G)|-1)/2 implies connectivity of G.
Also the left side of the proof also implies that G is Hamiltonian (possible to connect all vertices of G in a cycle) which could be relevant to its edge connectivity..

My understanding so far: I've been considering the vertex v, with deg(v)=d(G). Clearly, the edges whose removal will disconnect G will be connected to v (or some other vertex with minimum degree).
I can't seem to grasp the implications of the minimum degree being larger than half the order of G...

Sorry about my notation (first post)! And Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your statement is false. Take two $K_{\frac{p}{2}}$ connected by an edge. Then $d(G)=\frac{p}{2}$ but $k_1(G)=1$.

Comment: But isn't the minimum degree of any complete graph (or component) going to be equal to n-1 (for k_n)? (And therefore would not satisfy the left side of the statement?)

Comment: I'm considering a graph p=8. splitting into 2 k_4 components. d(g)=3 < p/2=4

Comment: You're right. Sorry for the mistake